# Boolean return prooblem scala

Tags: scala, boolean

Hi I am trying to get only true or false as a return but I am missing something

```
def filterOut[T](p: T => Boolean, as: List[T]): List[T] = {
  as.foldLeft(List[T]())((out, x) => 
                         if (p(x)) {x::out} else {out}
                        )}
```

Where p is a predicate. Can you help me please?

Comment: A language tag would be helpful.

Comment: Also try not to "tag spam". This has to do with a boolean result, but I do not see any boolean operators or much in the way of boolean logic.

Comment: @Fildor it is scala. Thank you for sugestion

Comment: The method clearly states that it is supposed to return `List[T]`. What would a `Boolean` return supposed to mean? That all values of `as` passed the predicate?

Comment: I guess you want something like `.all` or `.any` method on list.

Comment: @jwvh if it is like that 

`def filterOut[T](p: T => Boolean, as: List[T]): Boolean = {
as.foldLeft(List[T]())((out, x) => 
                         if (p(x)) {x::out} else {out}
                        )}`
and if for example predicate say is 2 in List(2,3,5,1) the return should be True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you required to use `foldLeft()`?

```
def atLeastOne[T](p: T => Boolean, as: Seq[T]): Boolean =
  as.foldLeft(false)(_ || p(_))
```

Or are you permitted to be more direct?

```
def atLeastOne[T](p: T => Boolean, as: Seq[T]): Boolean =
  as exists p
```

testing:

```
atLeastOne((x:Int) => x > 57, List(3,11,71,43,5))          //res0: Boolean = true
atLeastOne[Char]('w'.==, "abcdef")                         //res1: Boolean = false
atLeastOne[String](_.isEmpty, "this-and--that".split("-")) //res2: Boolean = true
atLeastOne[Float](_ < 1F, Vector())                        //res3: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is perfect. I didn't know the method exists works. Thank you